# Are datetime timestamps updated after pickling?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm creating a timestamp using datetime.date.today().day. Later in the code, this one shall be compared to another (current) timestamp, but just on the day-level: "If the current day is not the day of the former timestamp, do stuff".

To do this, I'm saving the first timestamp using pickle. Now I wonder, if the datetime-object will be auto-updated after pickle.load, if the loading date is not the "dumping" date. After all, the function is named "today"... I hope, this is not a stupid question and I managed to explain my issue properly.

Comment: No, timestamps are not autoupdated. I feel that you are mistake in comparing time. . It would be more helpful if you can provide details with code snippets.

Comment: Try `type(datetime.date.today().day)`. You will see it's an `int`. So it doesn't known anything about "today", it's just a number.

Comment: A small questions unrelated to the problem: why do you store the first timestamp using pickle, if you only use it "Later in the code"? Does your program stop execution, and then loads the last timestamp when resuming?

Comment: You might take a look at the [`arrow`](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) module providing much nicer approaches to time-related objects

Comment: Well, I use it later in the code, but the time og execution may differ from the respective session in which the timestamp was created. In other words: the aim is to save a timestamp recording that the file has been opened. If the the file/programm has not yet been opened that same day, I need to pop up some reminders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `datetime.datetime.today()` *creates* a new `datetime.datetime` object of the current moment. The object itself doesn't know how it was created, i.e. neither the function nor the function's intention. It only know when it was created, and this is what will be stored.

If you look at the documentation of the function (e.g. via `help(datetime.datetime.today`), it provides this:

> Current date or datetime:  same as `self.__class__.fromtimestamp(time.time())`

Now, `time.time()` provides the current timestamp, e.g. `1468585949.653488`. This is a plain number (`float` or `int`), which is constant *once created*. This number is then simply fed to `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`. For any given timestamp, this will always give you the same `datetime` [1].

```
In [12]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1468585949.653488)
Out[12]: datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 15, 14, 32, 29, 653487)
```

If you dump this object, you get a regular `datetime.datetime` object. It's just the plain class `datetime.datetime` and its data, no function or method reference such as `datetime.datetime.today`.

```
In [3]: print(pickle.dumps(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1468585949.653488),protocol=0))
# cdatetime  # class datetime.\
# datetime   #                datetime
# p0         # push last object (datetime.datetime) to stack as p0
# (S'\x07\xe0\x07\x0f\x0e \x1d\t\xf8\xb0'  # group '(' start, string 'S' from binary ('\x07...')
# p1         # push last object (string) to stack as p1
# tp2        # create tuple from last stack group, push to stack as p2
# Rp3        # call p0(*p2)
# .          # done
```

So, what does this piece of junk do? It looks up the object `datetime.datetime` as `p0`, stores the string `'\x07\xe0\x07\x0f\x0e \x1d\t\xf8\xb0'` as `p1`, creates the tuple `p2 = tuple((p1,))`, then calls `p0(*p2)`.

Or in other words, `datetime.datetime('\x07\xe0\x07\x0f\x0e \x1d\t\xf8\xb0')` is returned. Note that the argument to `datetime.datetime` is a *constant* string. This will always give you the original datetime:

```
In [30]: datetime.datetime('\x07\xe0\x07\x0f\x0e \x1d\t\xf8\xb0')
Out[30]: datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 15, 14, 32, 29, 653488)
```

[1] Baring differences in timezones etc.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't autoupdate after loading. To demonstrate it, check this small example:

```
import pickle
import datetime

today1 = datetime.datetime.today()
pickle.dump(today1, open('today','wb') )   

sleep(5) 
today2 = pickle.load(open('today','r')) 

# today1 => datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 15, 18, 6, 6, 578041)
# today2 => datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 15, 18, 6, 6, 578041)
```

You can see that even after a lag of 5 seconds, there is NO change in attributes (year, month, day, hour, sec .. etc) of datetime objects: `today1` and `today2`

Hope it helps : )